# jQuery seletor não encontra a si mesmo

Tags: jquery, seletores

Estava montando uma funcionalidade que tinha por objetivo encontrar outros `selects` com mesmo valor, quando me deparei com esta situação :

```js
jQuery('select[name="group2"]').val('emissao');

jQuery('select[name^="group"]').on('change', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  var o = null;
  console.log(o = jQuery('select[name^="group"][value="'+this.value+'"]'));
  console.log(o['selector']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="emissao">Data Emissao</option>
  <option value="entrada">Data Entrada</option>
</select>

<select name="group2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="emissao">Data Emissao</option>
  <option value="entrada">Data Entrada</option>
</select>
```

Note que ele ja possui o novo valor mesmo assim o seletor não o encontra.

Qual o precedimento para encontrar este `select`?

Comment: Tente `'select[name^="group"] option[value='+this.value+']'` lembre-se que você esta tentando acessar um objeto filho de select que é o option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema aqui é que estás a procurar o `value` nos atributos. Há uma diferença entre o que está nos atributos (que pode dizer-se ser o HTML, neste caso a versão original) e a propriedade `.value` que é dinâmica e vai mudando. Ou seja diferença entre o HTML e a sua representação em JavaScript DOM.

Para esse seletor funcionar era preciso o HTML do `<select>` ter `value="xxx"`, e no JavaScript já ia funcionar com:

```
var el = jQuery('select[name^="group"][value="emissao"]');
```

(Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/u1vyr6ae/2/)

Para fazeres o que procuras podes usar assim:

```
jQuery('select[name^="group"]').on('change', function() {
    var self = this;
    var selects = jQuery('select[name^="group"]').filter(function() {
        return this.value == self.value;
    });
    console.log(selects.length); // 2 quando os valores forem iguais
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1vyr6ae/